# SQLite3 table subtraction

Tags: sql, sqlite, subtraction

I have two tables; one is a reference table `all_grid` and the other has customer details on it `t_customer`.

I need to present the rows that are in the reference table but not in the customer table (i.e. show the rows where customer_x and customer_y columns are present in the `all_grid` but not in `t_customer`). Columns are named the same in both tables, but `t_customer` has an id column too.

Currently I've tried

```
SELECT customer_x, customer_y FROM all_grid
EXCEPT
SELECT customer_x, customer_y FROM t_customer;
```

but this seems to just show all rows in all_grid and I'm not sure which terminology to use for SQLite.

t_customer table is as follows:

```
1|35|24
2|-20|30
3|-10|-20
4|35|-46
5|4|-19
6|30|36
7|-12|-24
8|-12|-16
9|-17|-10
10|99|99
11|-4|-29
12|35|24
13|13|28
14|99|99
15|-24|-3
16|-49|-39
17|99|99
18|-48|-44
19|-46|35
20|-28|-47
21|99|99
22|99|99
23|31|22
24|4|14
25|5|6
26|32|24
27|-34|-4
28|29|25
29|-12|-31
30|99|99
31|-17|41
32|-20|-42
33|99|99
34|-4|40
```

and all_grid is all 100 possible mixes of customer_x and customer_y rounded down to the nearest 10, and (90, 90) included.

Comment: There must be a difference somewhere. Show some example data.

Comment: Thanks for your help @CL. but I realised my ignorance and did as described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I've realised that I did something stupid and didn't consider the fact that t_customer data was rounded up and down to 10 in prior calculations.

My final query was:

```
SELECT (customer_x * 10), (customer_y * 10) FROM all_grid
EXCEPT
SELECT 10 * (t.customer_x / 10), 10 * (t.customer_y / 10) FROM
(SELECT CASE WHEN customer_x < 0 THEN customer_x - 10 ELSE customer_x END AS customer_x,
CASE WHEN customer_y < 0 THEN customer_y - 10 ELSE customer_y END AS customer_y
FROM t_customer) t
```

and seems to do the trick.